# Difference Between ? and ! in Swift Language?

Tags: swift

I read a lot of articles online and book (Apple) but I am not able to find out the difference between ? and ! operator in Swift language.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
    {

    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }
```

In the code above the first func declares the tableView as ! and in the second function tableView is declared as ?.

Comment: those symbols are explained in the FREE swift books from Apple.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

As per the official Apple docs:

> When working with optional values, you can write ? before operations
>   like methods, properties, and subscripting. If the value before the ?
>   is nil, everything after the ? is ignored and the value of the whole
>   expression is nil. Otherwise, the optional value is unwrapped, and
>   everything after the ? acts on the unwrapped value. In both cases, the
>   value of the whole expression is an optional value.
>
> Once you’re sure that the optional does contain a value, you can
>   access its underlying value by adding an exclamation mark (!) to the
>   end of the optional’s name. The exclamation mark effectively says, “I
>   know that this optional definitely has a value; please use it.” This
>   is known as forced unwrapping of the optional’s value (...)

Apple Inc. 'The Swift Programming Language'. iBooks. https://itun.es/nl/jEUH0.l