# Printing without force-unwrapping property doesn't trigger runtime error in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, option-type, forced-unwrapping, optional-chaining

I have the below code and it works fine, but I was expecting the line `print(john.residence!.numberOfRooms)` to crash, as my `numberOfRooms` variable has `nil` value and I am not using forced wrapping when passing its value as argument to `print()`. Can anyone please explain why is this not triggering a runtime error and printing `nil` safely instead?

```
class Person {
    var residence: Residence?
}

class Residence {
    var numberOfRooms: Int?
}

let john = Person()

john.residence = Residence()

print(john.residence!.numberOfRooms)
```

Comment: Max. Just to clear things, you are not force unwrapping on a nil value. You are force unwrapping on john.residence and it has a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is called *Optional Chaining*. Both Optional Chaining and Forced Unwrapping do the same thing, but:

> The main difference is that optional chaining fails gracefully when
>   the optional is nil, whereas forced unwrapping triggers a runtime
>   error when the optional is nil.
>
> <sub>“The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2).” iBooks. https://itun.es/br/jEUH0.l</sub>

You're force unwrapping the `.residence` property, which is not `nil`: It contains a `Residence` instance, which has its `.numberOfRooms` property set as `nil` because it wasn't initialized. Since you're not force unwrapping it, no errors are given, due to optional chaining. Try force unwrapping the `.numberOfRooms` property instead to get an error:

```
print(john.residence!.numberOfRooms!)
```

Or, you can remove the following line to set `.residence` as `nil`:

```
john.residence = Residence()
```

This way `john` has no `.residence`, so trying to force unwrap it will make the Swift compiler throw a runtime error.

Comment: Ok makes sense, but one more question, why would i use john.residence!.numberOfRooms! when i can use john.residence!.numberOfRooms to get my value.

Comment: When using `.numberOfRooms!` you state that you're totally sure this property will not return `nil`. This is useful for debugging purposes, because if you were expecting a value not to be `nil` and it returns `nil`, your program will quickly stop execution. This will avoid indirect errors caused by values being `nil` where they shouldn't.

Comment: @Max see my updated answer for more explanation about what's optional chaining.

Answer (score 0):

Your app not crash because you have define property **numberOfRooms** with **?**. It means that it will allow null value also.

Use **!** instead of **?**. It will definitely crash on this statement.

```
 print(john.residence!.numberOfRooms)
```

Visit this link it will help you to understand the difference between ? and !.
[Difference Between ? and ! in Swift Language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496830/difference-between-and-in-swift-language)

Comment: What you're describing is an _implicitly unwrapped optional_, and the OP problem refers to why his code containing an _optional chain_ doesn't return a runtime error.

Comment: @Bhumilka john.residence!.numberOfRooms will not crash , please check. it would print a nil value

Comment: @Max he's saying that if you code the `Residence` initialization as `var numberOfRooms : Int!` (replacing **?** by **!** here) will cause the `print` function to fail. However, do not use this. More on Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24006975/why-create-implicitly-unwrapped-optionals