# I do not understand nil in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, crash

I've tried to read up on many of the postings before but I still seem to not be able to understand "nil".

```
let mass = Double(density! * volume!)
```

In this section of the code it tells me:

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

When I run my app it runs smoothly if I don't press the button while all the text fields are empty but when I do it crashes and the debugger tool tells me the error is here but I'm not sure why it doesn't work.
I just really don't understand the other nil explanation forums on Stack Overflow and Swift is very confusing for me as it is.

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var massInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var volumeInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var densityInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerOutput: UITextField!

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func calculateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        clearAnswer()
        mvdCalc()
        clearBoxes()
    }//end of btn

    //------------------------FUNCTIONS-----------------------------------

    func mvdCalc(){
        if massInput.text!.isEmpty {massFormula()}
        if volumeInput.text!.isEmpty {volumeFormula()}
        if densityInput.text!.isEmpty {densityFormula()}
    }//end of mvdCalc

    func clearBoxes(){
        massInput.text = ""
        volumeInput.text = ""
        densityInput.text = ""
    }//end of clear boxes

    func massFormula(){
        let density = Double(densityInput.text!)
        let volume = Double(volumeInput.text!)
        let mass = Double(density! * volume!)
        answerOutput.text = "\(mass)"
    }//end of mass

    func volumeFormula(){
        let density = Double(densityInput.text!)
        let mass = Double(massInput.text!)
        let volume = Double(mass! / density!)
        answerOutput.text = "\(volume)"
    }//end of volume

    func densityFormula(){
        let volume = Double(volumeInput.text!)
        let mass = Double(massInput.text!)
        let density = Double(mass! / volume!)
        answerOutput.text = "\(density )"
    }//end of density

    func clearAnswer() {
        if massInput.text == "" && volumeInput.text == "" && densityInput.text == "" {
            answerOutput.text = ""
        }
    }//end of clearAnswer

}//end of class
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24496830/difference-between-and-in-swift-language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app crashes because both `density` and `volume` are `nil`. If you force-unwrap a `nil` (by using the `!`), your app crashes.

Why are `density` and `volume` nil then?

Because the `Double` initialisers here returned `nil`:

```
let density = Double(densityInput.text!)
let volume = Double(volumeInput.text!)
```

This is caused by the strings you passed to it being in a wrong format. `densityInput.text` and `volumeInput.text` are not valid double strings. Why are they not valid? Well, as you said, the text fields are empty. Empty strings (`""`) can't be converted to a double.

To fix this, you can choose to not do the calculation if either one of the text fields are not valid:

```
if let density = Double(densityInput.text!), let volume = Double(volumeInput.text!) {
    let mass = density * volume
    answerOutput.text = "\(mass)"
}
```

If either is `nil`, the if won't run.

Do this for all your other calculations as well!

Comment: Thank you so much I got it working, thanks for the explanation I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes application will crash for of-course Answers in your question itself

You are calling this as your button Action

```
@IBAction func calculateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    clearAnswer()
    mvdCalc()
    clearBoxes()
}
```

**Step 1** Execution of `clearAnswer()` Goes well Because you just Clearing your textfields

**Step 2** When it comes to `mvdCalc()` Execution

```
let mass = Double(density! * volume!)
```

App crashed here - Look at the following screenshot

[image]

if you see Density value is Printed to console are densityStr was not ""

**and**

Printing mass Produced an Error because massStr was ""

So, To solve You Need to check before calling function to calculate Values

**as**

```
if mass != nil {
    print("call function")
    let massValue = Double(density! * volume!)
    answerOutput.text = "\(massValue)"
}
else{
    print("Value is empty no calculation to be performed")
}
```

Note : Do not clear your TF Values till you had not performed your calculation

Second, Do not call `mvdCalc()` till required TF for this block is Empty

Show Alert on button press that "Value for this TF is required " and if condition is Satisfied Execute **mvdCalc()**